# Submit multiple values from array in php

Tags: php

**here are the html :**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Pilih Item :</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php 
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        foreach($db->tampil_data_invoice($id) as $d){
            $lihatitem = mysql_query("select * from tbl_item where id_item ='$d[id_item]'");
            $item = mysql_fetch_array($lihatitem);
            $lihatkemasan = mysql_query("select * from tbl_harga_item where id_harga ='$d[id_harga]'");
            $kemasan = mysql_fetch_array($lihatkemasan);
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id_alokasi[]" value="$d[id_alokasi]"/><table class="table table-bordered data-table">
        <tr><th>Nama Item</th>
        <th>Kemasan</th>
        <th>Qty</th></tr>
        <tr><td>'.$item[nama_item].' </td><td>kemasan : '.$kemasan[kemasan].'</td><td>qty : '.$d[alokasi].'</td></table></br></tr>';
        }?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php 
$number = count($_POST["id_alokasi"]);  
if($number > 0)  
{  
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
    {  
        if(trim($_POST["id_alokasi"][$i] != ''))  
        {  
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '$id_invoice','$_POST[id_alokasi][$i])','')";  
            mysql_query($sql);  
        }  
    }  
?>
```

Can anybody help me here why **$_POST['id_alokasi']** return Array, not the value. is there any something wrong with the my code? thanks in advance

Comment: To count the number of items in a **$_POST** array, use `count($_POST)` not  `count($_POST['id_alokasi'])`

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\lipwih\datainvoice.php on line 20. this is the error

Comment: i just want to count 'id_alokasi' not all posted value.

Comment: Where is this line 20 pointing at?

Comment: `count` is used for getting the size of an array only. Mapping directly a value from `$_POST` would return either a single value or an array, depends on how you posted your data.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\lipwih\datainvoice.php on line 20
INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '9','Array[0])','')

Comment: $_POST["id_alokasi"] can you please var_dump this. I just want to see the result

Comment: Found this. In your SQL unexpected ) try replace this and run your script `$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '$id_invoice','$_POST[id_alokasi][$i]','')";`

Comment: Use `mysqli` because `mysql` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to read [PHP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

First of all - single quotes do not "understand" variables, so :

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id_alokasi[]" value="$d[id_alokasi]"/>
```

will just output input with value set to string '$d[id_alokasi]'

Next one, that even if you use double quotes, it doesn't understand complex constructions, so it can take simple array value, but not multidimentional, for this cases you need use concatenation or curly braces.

Your code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '$id_invoice','$_POST[id_alokasi][$i])','')";
```

failed because of that, it understand $_POST[id_alokasi], but not even try to take next [$i], php try to convert $_POST[id_alokasi] to string, so you have a notice.

you may write

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '$id_invoice','{$_POST[id_alokasi][$i]})','')";
```

And the last one, you should **NEVER** include user input into database query directly because of [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You should study "right way" things almost the same time as you studying "syntax things"

Answer (score 0):

Found this. In your SQL Query you added unwanted **)** (**Parentheses**) try replace the below code and run your script.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_item_invoice VALUES('', '$id_invoice','$_POST[id_alokasi][$i]','')";
```

Hope this Helps.